# lmdb stores the data inefficiently?

Tags: python, deep-learning, lmdb

I'm looking for a data file structure that enables fast reading of random data samples for deep learning, and have been experimenting with lmdb today. However, one thing that seems surprising to me is how inefficiently it seems to store the data.
I have an ASCII file that is around 120 GB with gene sequences.
Now I would have expected to be able to fit this data in a lmdb database of roughly the same size or perhaps even a bit smaller since ASCII is a highly inefficient storing method.
However what I'm seeing seems, to suggest that I need around 350 GB to store this data in a lmdb file and I simply don't understand that.
Am I not utilizing some setting correctly, or what exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
import time
import lmdb
import pyarrow as pa

def dumps_pyarrow(obj):
    """
    Serialize an object.

    Returns:
        Implementation-dependent bytes-like object
    """
    return pa.serialize(obj).to_buffer()

t0 = time.time()
filepath = './../../Uniparc/uniparc_active/uniparc_active.fasta'
output_file = './../data/out_lmdb.fasta'
write_freq = 100000

start_line = 2
nprot = 0

db = lmdb.open(output_file, map_size=1e9, readonly=False,
               meminit=False, map_async=True)
txn = db.begin(write=True)
with open(filepath) as fp:
   line = fp.readline()
   cnt = 1
   protein = ''
   while line:
       if cnt >= start_line:
           if line[0] == '>': #Old protein finished, new protein starting on next line
               txn.put(u'{}'.format(nprot).encode('ascii'), dumps_pyarrow((protein)))
               nprot += 1
               if nprot % write_freq == 0:
                   t1 = time.time()
                   print("comitting... nprot={} ,time={:2.2f}".format(nprot,t1-t0))
                   txn.commit()
                   txn = db.begin(write=True)
                   line_checkpoint = cnt
               protein = ''
           else:
               protein += line.strip()
       line = fp.readline()
       cnt += 1


txn.commit()
keys = [u'{}'.format(k).encode('ascii') for k in range(nprot + 1)]
with db.begin(write=True) as txn:
    txn.put(b'__keys__', dumps_pyarrow(keys))
    txn.put(b'__len__', dumps_pyarrow(len(keys)))

print("Flushing database ...")
db.sync()
db.close()

t2 = time.time()
print("All done, time taken {:2.2f}s".format(t2-t0))
```

Edit:
Some additional information about the data:

In the 120 GB file the data is structured like this (Here I am showing the first 2 proteins):

```
>UPI00001E0F7B status=inactive
YPRSRSQQQGHHNAAQQAHHPYQLQHSASTVSHHPHAHGPPSQGGPGGPGPPHGGHPHHP
HHGGAGSGGGSGPGSHGGQPHHQKPRRTASQRIRAATAARKLHFVFDPAGRLCYYWSMVV
SMAFLYNFWVIIYRFAFQEINRRTIAIWFCLDYLSDFLYLIDILFHFRTGYLEDGVLQTD
ALKLRTHYMNSTIFYIDCLCLLPLDFLYLSIGFNSILRSFRLVKIYRFWAFMDRTERHTN
YPNLFRSTALIHYLLVIFHWNGCLYHIIHKNNGFGSRNWVYHDSESADVVKQYLQSYYWC
TLALTTIGDLPKPRSKGEYVFVILQLLFGLMLFATVLGHVANIVTSVSAARKEFQGESNL
RRQWVKVVWSAPASG
>UPI00001E0FBF status=active
MWRAQPSLWIWWIFLILVPSIRAVYEDYRLPRSVEPLHYNLRILTHLNSTDQRFEGSVTI
DLLARETTKNITLHAAYLKIDENRTSVVSGQEKFGVNRIEVNEVHNFYILHLGRELVKDQ
IYKLEMHFKAGLNDSQSGYYKSNYTDIVTKEVHHLAVTQFSPTFARQAFPCFDEPSWKAT
FNITLGYHKKYMGLSGMPVLRCQDHDSLTNYVWCDHDTLLRTSTYLVAFAVHDLENAATE
ESKTSNRVIFRNWMQPKLLGQEMISMEIAPKLLSFYENLFQINFPLAKVDQLTVPTHRFT
AMENWGLVTYNEERLPQNQGDYPQKQKDSTAFTVAHEYAHQWFGNLVTMNWWNDLWLKEG
PSTYFGYLALDSLQPEWRRGERFISRDLANFFSKDSNATVPAISKDVKNPAEVLGQFTEY
VYEKGSLTIRMLHKLVGEEAFFHGIRSFLERFSFGNVAQADLWNSLQMAALKNQVISSDF
NLSRAMDSWTLQGGYPLVTLIRNYKTGEVTLNQSRFFQEHGIEKASSCWWVPLRFVRQNL
PDFNQTTPQFWLECPLNTKVLKLPDHLSTDEWVILNPQVATIFRVNYDEHNWRLIIESLR
NDPNSGGIHKLNKAQLLDDLMALAAVRLHKYDKAFDLLEYLKKEQDFLPWQRAIGILNRL
GALLNVAEANKFKNYMQKLLLPLYNRFPKLSGIREAKPAIKDIPFAHFAYSQACRYHVAD
CTDQAKILAITHRTEGQLELPSDFQKVAYCSLLDEGGDAEFLEVFGLFQNSTNGSQRRIL
ASALGCVRNFGNFEQFLNYTLESDEKLLGDCYMLAVKSALNREPLVSPTANYIISHAKKL
GEKFKKKELTGLLLSLAQNLRSTEEIDRLKAQLEDLKEFEEPLKKALYQGKMNQKWQKDC
SSDFIEAIEKHL
```

When I store the data in the database I concatenate all the lines making up each protein, and store those as a single data point. I ignore the headerline (the line starting with >).
The reason why I believe that the data should be more compressed when stored in the database is because I expect it to be stored in some binary form which I would expect would be more compressed - though I will admit I don't know whether that is how it would actually work (For comparison the data is only 70 GB when compressed/zipped).
I would be okay with the data taking up a similar amount of space in lmdb format, but I don't understand why it should take up almost 3 times the space as it does in ASCII format.

Comment: Why do you think the database will improve the storage space if all the data is expanded in ascii?

Comment: Please show something of the schema and a snippet of the raw data.

Comment: I have added additional information about the data, as requested.

Answer (score 3):

LMDB does not implement any sort of compression on data. 1Byte in memory is 1Byte on disk.

But its internals can amplify space required:

- data handling is in *pages* (generally 4KB)
- each "record" need to store additional structures for the b-tree (for key and data) and the count of *pages* occupied by key and data

Bottom line : LMDB is designed for FAST data access, not to save space.